# Start HorizontalScrollView Animation

Tags: android, animation, horizontalscrollview

I want to start HorizontalScrollView animation when I click a button.

When I click a button I see all the HorizontalScrollView at once on the screen, 
but I want to see the HorizontalScrollView enter to the screen slowly from the right, and I want it to stop after it enter 30% to the screen, 
and just after I scroll it with my finger, I will see the all HorizontalScrollView.

How can I do this?

Thank's.

Comment: For slowly appearance you can use the scale animation,and your 2nd question,i didnot get it well.

Comment: You asked 2 questions in your question here so i said i did not get your second question.got it?

Comment: The second question: I want my HorizontalScrollView appears on the screen after I click a button, and I want it appears just 30% of it on the screen at first, and just after I scroll it with my finger, I will see the all HorizontalScrollView

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what your requirement is. But if you are looking for a horizontalscrollview that continuously scrolls automatically this [project souurce](https://github.com/blessenm/SlideshowDemo) will help.